# 2 divs aligned to each other and centered in viewport stop being aligned in smaller viewports

Tags: html, css

I have a login box that's centered vertically and horizontally in the viewport using transform, I wanted to add a simple menu right next to that login box, but outside of it (2 divs next to each other). The first div (login box) has a static width, I aligned them by using float, and it kinda worked but stops working as soon as the viewport width gets smaller - then the divs are being put one under another, even though there's still space left in the viewport.

How can I make them stay like that despite different viewport widths? I also want to center the side-menu vertically to the login box.

Here's a very simple fiddle illustrating the problem:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.center-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px; /* increase the width and .b goes under .a */
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-container">
  <div class="a">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <ul>
     <li>Li 1</li>
     <li>Li 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch floats and check out flexbox...you'll never want to go back.  I constantly recommend this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Sidenote: I added min-width: 70px to the `div.b` tag as well as text was wrapping...`white-space: nowrap` might work there as well

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.center-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  display: flex;
  
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px; 
  height: 60px;
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px
}
```

```html
<div class="center-container">
  <div class="a">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <ul>
     <li>Li 1</li>
     <li>Li 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```